# character encoding - how utf-8 handles charactrers

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, character

So, I know that when we type characters, each character maps to a number in a character set and then, that number is transformed into a binary format so a computer can understand. They way that number is transformed into a binary format(how many bits gets allocated) depends on character encoding.

So, if I type L, It represents 76. Then 76 gets tranformed into 1 byte binary format because of let's say UTF-8.

Now, I've read the following somewhere:

> The Devanagari character क, with code point 2325 (which is 915 in
> hexadecimal notation), will be represented by two bytes when using the
> UTF-16 encoding (09 15), three bytes with UTF-8 (E0 A4 95), or four
> bytes with UTF-32 (00 00 09 15).

So, as you can see it says `three bytes with UTF-8 (E0 A4 95)`. how are E0 A4 95 bytes ? I am asking because i have no idea where `E0 A4 95` came from... Why do we need this ? if we know that code point is 2325, all we have to do is in order to use UTF-8, we know that utf-8 will need 3 bytes to transform 2325 into binary... Why do we need `E0 A4 95` and what is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E0 A4 95` is the 3-byte UTF-8 *encoding* of U+0915.  In binary:

```
   E   0    A   4    9   5  (hex)
11100000 10100100 10010101  (binary)
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx  (3-byte UTF-8 encoding pattern)
    0000   100100   010101  (data bits)

    00001001 00010101       (regrouped data bits to 8-bit bytes)
       0   9    1   5       (hex)

               U+0915       (Unicode code point)
```

The first byte's binary pattern `1110xxxx` is a lead byte indicating a 3-byte encoding and 4 bits of data. Follow on bytes start with `10xxxxxx` and provide 6 more bits of data.  There will be two following bytes after a 3-byte leading byte indicator.

For more information read the Wikipedia article on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and the standard [RFC-3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629).

Comment: where does 2325 come from as a code point ? Look at my question where I specifed the part i found on google.

Comment: That comes from the [Unicode specification](http://unicode.org/main.html).  Symbols are assigned code points, for example [Devangari](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf).  2325 is 915 hexadecimal and is the number assigned to `क`.